# android - how to update mutablieLiveData from another class

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-dialog

I've a mutableLiveData of list of items in my fragment and I have a custom dialog that I pass a single item from this list to it . this is my code:

```
adapter.itemPosPriceListener.observe(this, Observer { pos ->
                activity?.let { act ->
                    val dialog = DialogRoomPrices(act)
                    dialog.item.value = it.get(pos)
                }
            })
```

this is my dialog  :

```
class DialogRoomPrices(act: Activity) {
private var dialog: Dialog
private var act: Activity
val item = MutableLiveData<RoomItem>()

init {
    dialog = Dialog(act, R.style.DialogAnimation)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_room_prices)
    this.act = act

    makeDialog()
    val lp = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.window?.attributes)
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    dialog.getWindow()?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

    dialog.show()
    dialog.window?.attributes = lp
}
 private fun makeDialog() {
    item?.value?.let { row ->
        dialog.et_roomp_price_paye.setText(row.price_paye)
        dialog.et_roomp_price_akhathafte.setText(row.price_akhathafte)
        ////and 10 more rows of these 
    }

    dialog.bt_next.setOnClickListener {
        /////need to update the item and observe it in my fragment
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

as you can see ,dialog has a form and after filling the data and clicking on submit button , I need to update my item in fragment class .

the question is , how can I update the this item and notify my fragment's item about it ?

Comment: It is not a good practice to expose MutableLiveData to other classes. Livedata should be exposed as a property by returning the mutable livedata in  the getter method. I have few queries                                                                                     
1. Why do you want to change MutableLivedata content outside the class?                        2. In the line `it.get(pos)` what does `it` refers?. I believe `it` should be `activity` reference

Comment: @VaikundamRaghul thanks for reply  , 1- I've a recycleview and it has a button on it , when the button pressed, I need to open a dialog and be able user to modify the data , then he submit the data and then I need to update my adapter with the new contents .  2- it.get(pos) , it refers to my List of items

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the whole code, but such communication can be done simply with a [callback](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).

Solution will look like

```
class DialogRoomPrices(act: Activity) {

interface Listener() {
    fun onNext(data: SomeData)
}

private var listener: Listener?
private var dialog: Dialog
private var act: Activity
val item = MutableLiveData<RoomItem>()

...

dialog.bt_next.setOnClickListener {
    val dataToBeSetToHostingFragment = getData()
    listener?.onNext(dataToBeSetToHostingFragment)
    dialog.dismiss()
}
```

In the `Fragment`

```
class HostingFragment(): Listener {

adapter.itemPosPriceListener.observe(this, Observer { pos ->
                activity?.let { act ->
                    val dialog = DialogRoomPrices(act)
                    dialog.item.value = it.get(pos)
                    dialog.listener = object : DialogRoomPrices.Listener {
                        override onNext(data: SomeData) {
                            // Assign data to your liveData, force update recycler view or do any other action you want to
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```